# \newcommand environment when convert from markdown to pandoc

Tags: markdown, jupyter-notebook, mathjax, pandoc

I use ipython notebook to type math and then convert to latex. To make mathjax understand `\newcommand`, I have to put it inside `$...$`. For example, `$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$` works well with mathjax. The problem is that when I convert to tex file using pandoc, it is still `$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$` there, but what I want is just `\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}` (no `$...$`). Is there anyone please show me how to solve this problem?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hi have you tried to take a look at the "Verbatim code blocks" section of the [pandoc documentation](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example9/pandocs-markdown.html) ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: I tried but it seems that code blocks not work with mathjax. If I want `\newcommand...` in the tex file, I just type exactly the same in markdown (so code block is not important in my opinion). `$\newcommand...$` when is converted to tex file using pandoc, then compile just cause error.

Comment: Minmal working example?

Comment: What do you mean by "code block don't work with mathjax" ? You want to convert your md file in html too ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: I think that you have get my point. I didn't notice that. I type math in ipython notebook and it seems that ipython notebook converts markdown to html. Could you find any solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: Use the command line `pandoc -f markdown myfile.md -o myfile.tex`. I don't know ipython by the way.

Answer (score 1):

One easy option is to use latex magic to use latex environments within ipython.

For instance, here is an [example](http://www.slideviper.oquanta.info/nbcreveal/sky_test.html?theme=sky#/12/2)

`%%latex
\begin{aligned}
\nabla \times \vec{\mathbf{B}} -\, \frac1c\, \frac{\partial\vec{\mathbf{E}}}{\partial t} & = \frac{4\pi}{c}\vec{\mathbf{j}} \\
\nabla \cdot \vec{\mathbf{E}} & = 4 \pi \rho \\
\nabla \times \vec{\mathbf{E}}\, +\, \frac1c\, \frac{\partial\vec{\mathbf{B}}}{\partial t} & = \vec{\mathbf{0}} \\
\nabla \cdot \vec{\mathbf{B}} & = 0
\end{aligned}`

Alternatively, the only solution to using full blown latex within markdown cells is to use a configuration file for creating tex Macros in MathJax instead of overloading $...$.

First

1. Create a local MathJax installation (See ipython [docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/install/install.html))
2. Modify the local MathJax installation with a custom configuration file and tex macros. (References provided below)
3. Tell ipython to use your local-modified MathJax installation using

   ```
    python -m IPython.external.mathjax -d /some/other/mathjax
   ```

#### Modifying MathJax Installation

Here is a relevant snippet from the MathJax [Documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html)

> If you have many such definitions that you want to use on more than
>   one page, you could put them into a configuration file that you can
>   load along with the main configuration file. For example, you could
>   create a file in MathJax/config/local called local.js that contains
>   your macro definitions:
>
> ```
> MathJax.Hub.Config({   
>   TeX: {
>     Macros: {
>      RR: "{\\bf R}",
>      bold: ["{\\bf #1}",1]
> }   } });
> ```
>
> MathJax.Ajax.loadComplete("[MathJax]/config/local/local.js"); and then
>   load it along with your main configuration file on the script that
>   loads MathJax.js:
>
> ```
> <script src="/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML,local/local.js"></script>
> ```
>
> If you are using the CDN, you can make a local configuration file on
>   your own server, and load MathJax itself from the CDN and your
>   configuration file from your server. See Using a Local Configuration
>   File with the CDN for details.